# Call external MVC View in HTML Web Site Project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I Have a Solution with 2 projects (a Web Application and a Web Site):
[image: Solution with 2 Projects]

In Web Site project i have index.html and i want to call a view (Home/Index) from the Web Application project in a button:

[image: HTML Code]

Anyone have an ideia how i do that?

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done as the view's have to be routed through the controller and will not have access to external projects.

Any reason the two projects are seperated?

Comment: Hi, Richard!

The website project is my personal site and the web application is my system.

When the Login button is clicked i want to show the Login View of my system.

Comment: Okay, I'd suggest you merge the two to avoid further problems.